# Update em tabela mysql em loop

Tags: sql-update

Olá, Tenho uma tabela mysql que contém o número do aluno e a data da aula já registrados, e preciso atualizar o campo "PRESENTE" com "S" ou "N". Em outras palavras, registrar a chamada tradicional. Alguém poderia me dar uma sugestão?
Estou usando PHP . Tenho uma tabela que contem o número do aluno, a data da aula. Isto já resolvi. Agora preciso varrer esta tabela e ir captando para cada linha se o aluno esteve ou não presente. Estou utilizando um foreach mas não estou conseguindo captar o "S" ou "N" para atualizar cada linha

Comment: o que vc ja fez em php? só com isso não da pra saber o que está errado em seu código , poste o código que seja um  Exemplo completo, minimo e verificavel, caso não saiba o que é leia aqui : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ainda não tenho o código. Estou buscando uma orientação para uma estratégia para resolver o problema. Por exemplo: se usa um foreach  e dentro do laço faz tal coisa, etc. Não seria necessário elaborar o código, apenas indicar uma estratégia.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE aluno SET presente = 'S' WHERE numero = ? AND data = ?
```

Ou então:

```sql
UPDATE aluno SET presente = 'N' WHERE numero = ? AND data = ?
```

No `?` você coloca o número do aluno e a data.

Comment: O problema é como captar antes o "S" ou o "N". São 30 ou 40 linhas na tabela. Cada registro poderá ser updated com "S" ou "N".

Comment: @Rui Então o seu problema não é montar a SQL. O seu problema é alguma outra coisa. Edite a pergunta e informe direito qual é o seu problema, a começar com a linguagem de programação que você está usando e com o código que já tem para realizar a chamada.

Comment: Estou usando PHP . Tenho uma tabela que contem o número do aluno, a data da aula. Isto já resolvi.  Agora preciso varrer esta tabela e ir captando para cada linha se o aluno esteve ou não presente. Estou utilizando um foreach mas não estou conseguindo captar o "S" ou "N" para atualizar cada linha.

Comment: @Rui Então edite a pergunta para deixar isso claro a todos, do contrário não vai conseguir respostas muito melhores que a minha.